# an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, windows, forms, backcolor

I'm really a newbie at programming so do excuse me if my knowledge seems really inadequate. I'm doing a C# project for my school and I'm having problems with my homework, thanks

some codes in here:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    child frm2 = new child();
    frm2.ShowDialog();


    int color = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    i = rnd.Next(51);

    frm2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i*color);
    frm2.ShowDialog();
    if (color == 5)
    {
        color = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the first ShowDialog()...

Comment: thank you my friend but it still does not work.

Comment: Post the stacktrace here to show which line is causing the exception

Comment: frm2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i*color);     this line

Comment: Your i*color will always be 0, as you don't ever set color to a different value

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira That would not cause a program throw arg exception though.

Comment: @horadus Post a stack trace of exception. Problem is something else.

Comment: i*color is not main problem but therefore it helps me to get the mistake and solve it :) thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
frm2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i*color);
```

Since your `i` variable is 0 (zero), the resulting color is transparent, and the exact exception message you are getting should be like this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Control does not support transparent background colors.

In order to fix it, correct your logic for `i` and `color` variables and use the following:

```
frm2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.FromArgb(i * color));
```

which removes the transparency from the generated color - see [Color.FromArgb Method (Int32, Color)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: also, you will need to set the variable color to something other than 0